# How to color ls according to file extension in iterm2?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

I would like all directories to have one color, all .txt files to have another common color, etc. How can I achieve this? Coreutils colors files according to their permissions (I think).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to install `coreutils` and `dircolor` ([link here](https://github.com/gibbling/dircolors)), and map different colors to different file extensions as given by [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322029/how-to-change-the-color-of-different-files-in-ls).

Answer (score 1):

By default, `ls -G` lists the directory contents coloured where,

1. directories are blue,
2. shared directories are black with yellow background,
3. executables are red (includes .mp4, .mp3 files),
4. others are white (like .zip, .pdf, .csv, other media files)

To change the colours as required from default, 2 environment variables must be set, namely `CLICOLOR` `LSCOLORS`.

1. Open `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`
2. Add the following lines.

   ```
   export CLICOLOR=1
   export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced #(for dark backgrounds)
   export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad #(for light background)
   ```
3. Save it and comiple as `source <filename>`.
4. Now do `ls`.

These combinations can be formed as per requirements by following the `man` page of `ls`.

> The value of this variable describes what color to use for which attribute when colors are enabled with CLICOLOR.  This string is a concatenation of pairs of the format fb, where f is the fore-ground color and b is the background color.
>
> The color designators are as follows:
>
> - a - black
> - b - red
> - c - green
> - d - brown
> - e - blue
> - f - magenta
> - g - cyan
> - h - light grey
> - A - bold black, usually shows up as dark grey
> - B - bold red
> - C - bold green
> - D - bold brown, usually shows up as yellow
> - E - bold blue
> - F - bold magenta
> - G - bold cyan
> - H - bold light grey; looks like bright white
> - x - default foreground or background
>
> Note that the above are standard ANSI colors.  The actual display may differ depending on the color capabilities of the terminal in use.
>
> The order of the attributes are as follows:
>
> 1. directory
> 2. symbolic link
> 3. socket
> 4. pipe
> 5. executable
> 6. block special
> 7. character special
> 8. executable with setuid bit set
> 9. executable with setgid bit set
> 10. directory writable to others, with sticky bit
> 11. directory writable to others, without sticky bit